# Whitelist phones for DISA in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip, freepbx

What would be the best practice to allow only a whitelisted list of numbers to access a DISA system in asterisk?

I have a public number that lot of people use but if a certain number calls, it allow to access DISA and have internal dial.

I was thinking on using specific inbound routes for every number, but its difficult to maintain and having >30 inbound routes doesn't seem very nice.

Thanks!

Comment: Put the DISA on an extension, and be sure it has a PIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do this is to use the built-in [Asterisk Database functions](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+Internal+Database).  Each incoming CID has a PIN that they have to enter.

When a call to the DISA trunk comes in, I check for a known CID.  If not, I route the call to the IVR.  If the CID is known, I then answer the call and request the PIN code.  3 strikes, and the call is sent to the operator.  If the PIN is good, I give DISA access.

When a given person is no longer allowed DISA access, remove the DB entry for their CID.

A simple Ruby CGI / AMI lets me maintain the list of valid DISA CID/PIN combinations via a web browser.

If you want to be very secure, write a script that every 90 days changes all CID-chained PIN codes, and emails the users their new code.  It's not very hard to do, and makes for a relatively bullet-proof system.